# java cannot find or load main class in my two-class program

Tags: java, javac

Using Java in Eclipse, I wrote a two-class program to systematically solve Aristotle's [19] Number Puzzle.  My answer matches Aristotle's. :-) 'Nineteen.java' contains main(), the logic for solving, and swing code to display a frame, five panels, and 19 KTile19 objects. 'KTile19.java' extends JButton to make a custom button to show my scheme in progress. 'Nineteen' is in the default package. 'KTile19' is in package 'lassoObjects'.

I want to send my solution to my grandson to run on his PC from the Windows Command Prompt. But I had a beast of a time with your "common problem that new Java developers" have: Could not find or load main class Nineteen. When I won the battle, it was a grim victory.

I would like my grandson to install my two .java files somewhere below C:\Program Files\Java\LAsso. What would be the best and simplest 'javac' command(s) to compile my .java files? What would be the matching 'java' command to run the program? And what would be the matching folder structure that he should create?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: He should stay in the project root and `javac` the fullpath (with packages)

Comment: Why can't you just export your Eclipse project to a zip, send it, then tell him to import back to Eclipse?

Comment: To Royal Bg:  He has nothing on his PC except Java itself and an empty C:\Program Files\Java\LAsso folder.  He can easily create subfolders and copy my two .java source files anywhere I tell him to.  Since he has a clean easel, what would be the best subfolder(s) to create to contain my two files?  What would be the javac command(s) to compile my code?  And what would be the java command to run the compiled  program?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to create a Manifest.mf file that has the fully qualified Java class name in it.  The Manifest gets packaged with your jar file.  From there you can send it to your Grandson and he needs to Open is with Java.

Easy way to a manifest...In Eclipse :

- Right-click on the Eclipse Project.
- Select Export...
- Navigate to Java > JAR file.
- Next >
- Browse and Name the JAR file
- Next >
- Next > (again)
- Enable the Generate a Manifest file option.
- Save manifest in the workspace...probably your Eclipse project.
- At the bottom, type in (or Browse) your Java class with main().
- Click Finish.

Eclipse Project structure :

```
- Nineteen
  - src 
    - (default package)
      - Nineteen.java 
    - lassoObjects
      - KTile19.java 
  - Manifest.mf
```

When you Export your Manifest.mf should look like :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Nineteen
```

Here's my Java classes for a very simple setup...

Nineteen.java

```
import lassoObjects.KTile19;

public class Nineteen {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KTile19 lnewKTile = new KTile19 ();
        lnewKTile.doSomething ();

    }

}
```

KTile19.java

```
package lassoObjects;

import java.io.PrintStream;

public class KTile19 {

    public  PrintStream     Log = System.out;
    public  void    doSomething () {
        Log.println("I will start running Aristotle's problem.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick response!

Comment: Confusion:  This stackoverflow page says that lincolnadym "answered yesterday," but there is no answer shown.  ??

Comment: To test my JAR file, I ran it with: 
java -jar Nineteen.jar -- and got: Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: lassoObjects/KTile19.  I got the same error any 
number of times when trying to use 'javac' and 'java' commands. I noticed that 
the .mf file does not mention class KTile19. Ideas? A shortcoming in the 
JAR/manifest approach is that I don't learn anything about my javac/java problems.

Comment: Hi, are you running Windows or nix?  try , Command Prompt (console), cd <dir-with-jar>, java -cp .:Nineteen.jar lassoObjects.KTile19 (nix) ... java -cp .;Nineteen.jar lassoObjects.KTile19 (Windows).  I'm assuming your Java package is lassoObjects and the Java class with the main() is KTile19.

Comment: I just re-read your original post.  Nineteen.java has main().  do java -cp .;Nineteen.jar Nineteen .  Also, post the Manifest.mf and some of your Eclipse Project structure...i.e. Java package names, Java class names.  Also, to do a javac command you need to have JAVA_HOME set...what is JAVA_HOME set to...from the command prompt, echo %JAVA_HOME%.

Comment: Sorry for slow response.  I'm running Windows XP Pro Service Pack 3 
(soon to be upgraded).  'KTile19' is in package 'lassoObjects'.  
'Nineteen.class' does contain main().  

Eclipse Project structures:
  Everything starts out with:  K:\Program Files\Java

When Eclipse built the KTile19 project, I got:
\KTile19
   .settings
   bin
      lassoObjects
         KTile19.class
   src
      lassoObjects
         KTile19.java

When Eclipse built the Nineteen project, I got:
\Nineteen
   .settings
   bin
      Nineteen$1.class
      Nineteen.class
   src
      Nineteen.java

Comment: Tried to describe my .jar and manifest efforts, but it was too long.

Comment: Ah.  Nineteen is in one Eclipse project and KTile19 is in another Eclipse project?  For two classes, just put them both in the same project.  There's no need to have 2 separate Projects.  See my latest posts to the Answer...

Comment: Thank you for your example code! I have learned a LOT. I can have one project with multiple classes from which to build my program. Or I can build one program from multiple projects. When building a JAR file in Eclipse, you must select ALL the projects involved on the 'JAR File Specification' page. 
The -cp option of the 'java' command accepts both '.' and '..' like MS-DOS. :-) If you code the -cp option, you must provide paths to ALL .class files in any order. Upper/lowercase is ignored in the -cp option.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  I didn't know there were multiple Eclipse projects until your comment on 03/27...It's probably much easier to just lump all the Java classes into a single Eclipse Project...much easier to manager.  Have fun!

Comment: Q1: I construct Aristotle's hexagonal shape from 19 extended JButtons (my KTile19s). To build the hexagon, I use 5 JPanels containing 3,4,5,4,3 KTile19s. The code examines all possible combinations of numbers and shows the process by displaying the current combi with KTile19[].setText(). That works fine, but the entire hexagon occasionally wiggles left and right by one pixel. The KTile19s are plenty large enough to display two digits. Why the wiggle?

Comment: Q2: I tried to enhance the animation by adding some code in the actionPerformed() method, and the animation stopped after showing the 1st number in the 1st Tile. I cut the added code down to 1 stmt: 'if (tNbr == 9) tNbr++;' and the animation still stopped. Removed the 1 stmt, and the animation works fine. Why would such a benign stmt stop the animation? I'd be glad to send anything.

Comment: Item Q2 above was caused by my coding error.  Please ignore item Q2.